# Get Full Object From Oracle Object Storage using Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, async-await, fs, object-storage

I am working on an nodejs image server to read and write images on Oracle Object Storage.
The issue I am having is not getting the full image when using the function getObject using the Javascript api from oci-objectstorage

I have succesfully stored the following images.
1x1 image with the size of 70 bytes and another
5120 x 3200 image with size 2.9 MB

When I use the function getObject I am able to retrieve the full 1x1 image but when I attempt it with the 5120 x 3200 image, I can only get 15KB of 2.9MB
I used the following example from Oracle
https://github.com/oracle/oci-typescript-sdk/blob/master/examples/javascript/objectstorage.js

Below is the code that I am using to read the image from Oracle Object Storage
I have the below code in an async function.

```
router.get('/data/', async function (req, res, next) {
 let path = req.query.image_data

 fs.access(imagePath, fs.F_OK, async (err) => {
 if (err) {
 const provider = new common.ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider();
 const client = new os.ObjectStorageClient({
            authenticationDetailsProvider: provider
          });

const compartmentId = config.COMPARTMENTID
const bucket = config.BUCKET
const request = {};
const response = await client.getNamespace(request);
const namespace = response.value;
const getObjectRequest = {
            objectName: imagePath,
            bucketName: bucket,
            namespaceName: namespace
          };
const getObjectResponse = await client.getObject(getObjectRequest);

const head = getObjectResponse.value._readableState.buffer.head.data.toString('base64')
const tail = getObjectResponse.value._readableState.buffer.tail.data.toString('base64')



 await fs.writeFile(imagePath, completeImage,  {encoding: 'base64'},function(err) {

           if (err) return 
              res.sendFile(path, {root: './imagefiles'}) //using express to serve the image file
          });


}
 //file exists
  res.sendFile(path, {root: './imagefiles'});
})
})
```

It seems to me that the head and tail both have the same data. I am trying to then write the image using fs.write which then with the large image only write a small portion of the image while with the small 1x1 image it writes the full image.

I am not sure if its an issue with my use of the async/await setup or I may have to use a better implementation using promises that may allow to download the full image.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Another small issue I am having is serving the image after writing it. On the webpage I get an error saying could not display the image because it contains errors. But after I refresh the page again, which finds the image since it now exists on disk, it is able to display the image and does not show the previous error.